# Get response headers for request created by browser

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, eval

Suppose index.html has script which has url to external js file (*example.js*):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/example.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

What I have tried it's create XMLHttpRequest and than manually execute script with `window.eval(request.responseText)`. Any other ways?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @CharlieFish is actually all code that needs

Comment: @CharlieFish I am asking about approaches which can be used to get response headers for request for file... As I mentioned, I have tried to use  XMLHttpRequest and than execute js code as string by eval function. Perhaps exist another way. That I am interesting in.

Comment: You are correct. Currently with the way your question is phrased it's kinda hard to understand your question. I would remove `What possible ways I have if I want to access response headers for this file (example.js)?` so that it puts more focus on your question about `Any other ways?`. Your question isn't about possible ways. It's about other ways from what you have done so far.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: @CharlieFish makes sense, thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

To get the response headers when you make a request to server:

**Vanilla JS**:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("GET", "/some_url", true);
client.send();
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == this.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
        console.log(client.getResponseHeader("some_header"));
    }
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/some_url',
    success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
        console.log(request.getResponseHeader('some_header'));
    },
    error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(request.getResponseHeader('some_header'));
    }
});
```